# Clang compiler error: invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

Tags: macros, clang, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

using clang compiler on windows throws "invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression"

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
```

./bits/types.h:42:16: error: invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression

To make sure __WORDSIZE is defined, i have added

```
#define __WORDSIZE
```

which throws warning `./bits/wordsize.h:8:9: warning: '__WORDSIZE' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]` as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor expression technically isn't quite `__WORDSIZE == 64`; but, rather, it is produced *from* those tokens.  Before building the actual expression, the tokens in the expression are scanned; macro expansion takes place.  That's kind of the point; you want to check if a defined macro `__WORDSIZE` is 64.

If it turns out that `__WORDSIZE` is *not* expanded during this scan, then you get `__WORDSIZE == 64` as an expression; in that particular case, any remaining identifiers are treated as `0` before evaluating... which means you're evaluating the expression `0 == 64`, which is false.

But in your case, you're defining an object like macro `__WORDSIZE` with an empty replacement list.  So after the expansion, you simply get: `== 64`.  The first token there is `==`, but that's supposed to be a binary operator.  That's invalid; i.e., your `invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression` is `==`.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate about the correct way of defining and testing a variable, so that these expressions work as the OP intended?

Comment: You need to define the variable.  The correct way being 
```#define __WORDSIZE (64U)```